# empty UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an `UICollectionView` that shows stores in a particular city. A particular city might not have any stores at all, so in that case I should update the UICollectionView to be empty. When I make `nil` the data parameter, the app crashes saying the data parameter cannot be nil.

How can I empty the UICollectionView? In that case, besides showing no cells at all, I'd like to show a background-image informing the user that there are no stores, or removing the collectionView all together.

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have an array with data to create yours cells.

You can add a label above your collection view and hide this label if there is cell or display this label if there is no cell.

So, when you calculate your array, add a test :

```
self.myLabel.hidden = (_data.count > 0);
```

And you have this method to return the number of cells (_data.count = 0 if there is no data)

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _data.count;
}
```

Comment: What does "? NO : YES" do? I've never seen that before.

Comment: it's a ternary operation.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code of your .m please ?

Comment: I had an stupid error that had nothing to do with the collectionView, but weirdly it triggered after collectionView:numberOfItemInSection:. Thanks tough!

Answer (score 2):

I Would personally go with anther proper solution, you can create your own [custom view](http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6) and load this view in the background view of the UICollectionViw like this:

```
collectionView?.backgroundView = yourCustomView
```

This will contain a proper message for the users that there are no stores in that location.
Surly, you have to hide or show it according to the data count on viewWillAppear like this:

```
collectionView?.backgroundView.isHidden = _data.count == 0
```

or like this:

```
collectionView?.backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```